# If $u$ is complex valued and harmonic on a connected open set, and if $u^2$ is harmonic, then either $u$ is holomorphic or $\bar{u}$ is

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I don't even know where to start, so some starting points would be appreciated. Thanks!

(Greene and Krantz Function Theory of one complex variable, Chapter 7 ex. 13)

Comment: One place it is often good to start is with the definitions, another is with known consequences (the theorems and propositions already shown to be true).  For help with these, you need to give a bit more background as to what you already know. A third thing to think about is "what might the obstructions be to this being true?" or "what happens if I try to construct a counter-example?" [This last is not normally the first place to go]

Comment: This can be done in various ways -  the laplacian is $4u_{z\bar z}$ and same for $u^2$ from which you get $u_zu_{\bar z}=0$ etc; or show that if $f,g$ holomorphic then $f\bar g$ is harmonic iff one of them is constant and use the local representation of $u=f+\bar g$ with $f,g$ holomorphic etc

Comment: I think I have something... $f= u+iv$ and $g= u^2 + iw$ are both holomorpic functions. After substitution in $f-iv=u$ in $g$, I get that $g=(f-iv)(f+iv)+i(w-2v)$, so $g=u\bar u + i(w-2v)$ which means that $u\bar u$ is harmonic... close but not quite what I want

Comment: @Conrad By $u_{z}u_{\bar z}$ I assume you mean $(u_x+iu_y)(u_x-iu_y)$ right? And if so, I don't follow how that result proves the proposition, could you elaborate?

Comment: There is a $1/2$ in there at each but yes $u_z=(u_x-iu_y)/2$ and $u_{\bar z}=(u_x+iu_y)/2$ (by duality signs change from $dz=dx+idy$ etc; then C-R says that $u$ holomorphic iff $u_{\bar z}=0$ and antiholomorphic iff $u_z=0$ so if the product is zero, the usual connectivity arguments show that at least one of those must be identically zero etc

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the help!